# How do I move a volume group with two disks to another machine?

Tags: usb

I have configured a volume group from two USB disks on one machine and put data on it. I need to temporarily use that two-disk volume group on another machine. When I turn off the second machine, put those two disks into it and boot the machine, disk check on the machine gets confused and drops me into maintenance mode. When I then reboot that machine, the volume group works ok. What should I do so the two-disk volume group is always handled properly by the second machine ? I'm running the latest version of Buster on the new machine, and an older OS on the machine where I created the volume group.

I reviewed vgexport and vgimport, but they're only for one disk not two.

Comment: What are these machines? Are they Raspberry Pies? If so, what version? Are they identical?

Comment: Both are PI Zeros but with different versions of Raspbian. I want to take a volume group that is a pair of USB disks from one machine and use it on other like machines WITHOUT having to do a fresh LVM setup on the new machines since that presumably clobbers any data on the disks. Since USB drives and thus /dev/sdX change depending on how many drives are installed in a machine, and how many times drives have been plugged in and removed, there must be some files somewhere that tell LVM how to access the drives despite these variables.